# Dynamic index for promotions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm new to Stackoverflow, so perhaps my request is not immediately in correct format. I was working on a assignment for my employer and would like to automate more, outside scope of assignment of employer and just curious about whether my proposed solution is possible without a VBA-macro.

Situation:
I have a master file of promotions in Excel in which I would like to allow changes over time with respective dates (DateTo and DateFrom). Because changes might occur frequently I would like to apply logic to the initial value.

Please note that I'm not looking for a macro, I would like to have a formula.

In order to get this data I would like to build a dynamic index that checks:

1. Whether values are available in either FirstName and NextName besides in the specific row. For more guidance please check example and expected value in file.
2. If this is the case add FirstName and NextName and DateTo to the dynamic index. This will create an index for sequential flow of a promotion e.g. PromotionB1 to PromotionB4 and everything in between. Again demonstrated in example dynamic index for PromotionZ.
3. Return based on the earliest date in column C the value of column A, ie PromotionZ.

Example dynamic index for promotionZ

| FirstName | NextName | DateFrom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PromotionZ1 | PromotionZ2 | 01/01/2024 |
| PromotionZ2 | PromotionZ3 | 06/01/2024 |

Example data:

| FirstName | NextName | DateFrom | DateTo | ExpectedValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PromotionB1 | PromotionB2 | 01/01/2024 | 15/01/2024 | PromotionB1 |
| PromotionB2 | PromotionB3 | 16/01/2024 | 20/01/2024 | PromotionB1 |
| PromotionB3 | PromotionB4 | 21/01/2024 |  | PromotionB1 |
| PromotionA1 | PromotionA2 | 01/01/2024 | 19/01/2024 | PromotionA1 |
| PromotionZ1 | PromotionZ2 | 01/01/2024 | 05/01/2024 | PromotionZ1 |
| PromotionA2 | PromotionA3 | 20/01/2024 | 22/01/2024 | PromotionA1 |
| PromotionA3 | PromotionA4 | 23/01/2024 |  | PromotionA1 |
| PromotionZ2 | PromotionZ3 | 06/01/2024 |  | PromotionZ1 |

Comment: You have tagged both Excel AND Google Sheets. Would you please clarify this and select one tag or the other, but not both. Regarding the sample data and sample output, please don’t provide this information by way of image (it’s too hard for users to recreate). Would you please edit the question to include the sample data and expected outcomes in the body of the question-you can use Markdown  tables for this

Comment: Both requests updated, thanks for the review!